# QtWebEngine to access a named pipe or unix domain socket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, user-interface, deployment

Is there a way to use the `QtWebEnginge` to connect to a Windows named pipe or a UNIX domain socket? I have three main reasons for this configuration:

1. A user interface to one service / daemon that can be accessed from different system users.
2. We already have a HTML user interface
3. It is unnecessary to open a TCP Port that can also be accessed from other machines.

This is the `socat` version:

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" | socat unix-connect:/tmp/td-socket STDIO | head
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 16:43:47 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Is there a way to hack the `QtWebEngine` to access a named pipe / unix domain socket? I couldn't find an interface for this, especially as the `QtWebEngine` doesn't use the `QNetworkAccessManager` in the background.

As an alternative, is there a way to deploy (or use) a (bundled) browser in a Desktop app that can access this on Windows (or possibly Linux)?

It is unfortunately not enough to just load a HTML page into the engine as the UI depends on JS calls to load data from the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use websockets?

Comment: @MrEricSir web sockets solve a different problem: providing a two way communication between browser and server. I would like to know how I can use a browser  as a UI locally